# HTTP server in Android emulator not accessible from host

Tags: android

On my Android emulator device I have deployed HTTP server on port 8080

```
> adb -s 127.0.0.1 shell
generic_x86:/ $ netstat -atn
Active Internet connections (established and servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:47344  ::ffff:66.102.1.18:5228 ESTABLISHED
```

However, when I try to access it from the host the port seems to closed:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
```

In my host Resource Manager I am not seeing any process listening on that port

[image]

Why is the port not visible on host?

Comment: From official docs: *Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service that isolates it from your development machine network interfaces* ...

Comment: More interesting part of the doc(for you) is called: *Using network redirection*

Comment: @Selvin Thank you. Giving a link here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection) says that (thanks to @Selvin):

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service that isolates it from your development machine network interfaces .
> and then explain how to open specific ports by

> Using network redirection

In my case implementation the steps helped

```
telnet localhost 5554
auth ... # with token
redit add tcp:8080:8080
quit
```

And voila, HTTP server has become available on my host machine.
Now,